# Realizar ação ao fechar navegador

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, navegador-de-internet

Estou com um sistema que marca se a pessoa está *disponível* ou *indisponível* . Existe um botão chamado **sair**. Se a pessoa clica nele quando ela está disponível, então automaticamente altera o status do banco de dados para indisponível. Só que alguns usuários do site estão clicando no **X**, sendo assim a pessoa continua como *disponível* só que na verdade ela não está mais logada no site. Andei pesquisando e algumas pessoas falavam para usar a função `unload` ou `onBeforeUnload` pois as duas tem uma diferença. Gostaria de saber qual dessas duas usar e se por acaso alguém sabe como fazer uma requisição **$.post()** com jQuery quando a pessoa clicar no *X*

Comment: O propósito é fazer tipo chat ou ver usuários online?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode considerar usar uma lógica pra determinar se a pessoa está online ou não! Exemplo, crie em sua tabela no banco de dados um campo chamado ping_usuario ai você pode criar uma função ajax que chama essa mesma url a cada 10 segundos.

> Exemplo:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({url:'ping_user.php'});
},10000);
```

> **arquivo ping_user.php**

```
<?php
     session_start();
     $login = $_SESSION['login']; // Aqui a variavel de sessão que identifica o usuario.

     //inclui seu arquivo de conexao.
     include('conexao.php');

     //Efetua um update.
     mysql_query("UPDATE tb_login SET ping_usuario=NOW() WHERE login='$login'",$link_conexao); // Aqui usei o mysql_query para efetuar o update porem eu recomendo que estude a iteração com o banco através do PDO.

?>
```

Depois disso faça o inverso, declare como online a pessoa com um intervalo menor que 20 segundos.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE ping_usuario <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -20 SECOND)
```

Assim se o usuario fechar ou a energia dele acabar por exemplo ele não ira atualizar o ping, logo o seu algoritmo de busca vai identificar e considerar o mesmo offline.

***obs: o campo ping_usuario deve ser do tipo DATETIME**

Comment: Qualquer dúvidas sobre a implementação em seu algoritmo pode me contatar no http://www.hiago.me