# Auto logout quando fecho browser

Tags: php

Utilizo uma base de dados SQLite para fazer o login em que verifica se o utilisador existe. O que quero fazer é fechar a sessão quando a janela do browser é fechada. Tenho uma página que faz o logout, se for chamada.

```
$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Não tem nada que garanta que o *browser* feche a sessão. O que normalmente é feito é a sessão ter um tempo de expiração e considerar fechada após esse tempo de inatividade. De qualquer forma acho que já foi respondido. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33867/realizar-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-fechar-navegador Isso não parece ser problema de PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer que a sessão feche quando ele feche a janela então use o $_SESSION ao inves do $_COOKIE, agora a sessão só será destruida quando o Navegador inteiro for encerrado e não apenas uma aba.

O que você também poder fazer é usar um timestamp, por exemplo, depois de 5 minutos se o usuário tentar usar a página a sessão estará expirada, para isso você precisa salvar o timestamp na sessão toda vez que ele a carregar qualquer página, e então antes de salvar o novo timestamp verificar se do último carregamento até agora já se passaram 5 minutos

Um exemplo rústico:

pagina.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $tempo_limite_em_minutos = 5; // 5 minutos

    // se já foi definido vamos ver se a sessão ainda está valida
    if(isset($_SESSION['TEMPO'])){

        $tempo_desde_o_ultimo_carregamento = time() - $_SESSION['TEMPO'];
        if($tempo_desde_o_ultimo_carregamento / 60.0 > $tempo_limite_em_minutos){
            include 'logout.php';
            die();
        }

    }else{
        echo '<h1>Primeiro login</h1><br>';
    }

    // senão vamos apenas atualizar a sessão e mostra o conteudo que ele quer ver 
    $_SESSION['TEMPO'] = time();


echo '<h1>Você está logado</h1>
    <p>O php é uma ótima linguagem de programação, principalmente se você tem pouca memória no seu servidor</p>';
```

logout.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    session_destroy();

    echo '<h1>Desculpe, a sua sessão expirou :/';
```