# Como evitar multiplos acessos com o mesmo login e senha

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso complementar o código abaixo de forma que caso o usuário esteja logado não tenha como outra pessoa acessar a área restrita com mesmo login e senha em quanto o usuário que usou aquele acesso estiver ativo. De forma que caso ele feche o navegador ou efetue o logout a seção seja destruída liberando assim o acesso a essa conta.

Juntamente com isso a colocação de um botão de lembrar locação no painel de formulário de login.

Segue abaixo a MySQL junto com os códigos.

Mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `membros` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'admin',
  `autor` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Ryumaru',
  `senha` char(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'admin',
  `idade` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'exemplo@email.com',
  `cargo` enum('Adminstrador','Editor','Upload') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Adminstrador',
  `data_cadastro` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_ultimo_login` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `arquivo_data_cad` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2014-05-03',
  `arquivo_hora_cad` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '11:11:11',
  `ativado` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `membrosDados` (`id`,`login`,`senha`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

verificar.php

```
<?php

session_start();  // Inicia a session

include "config.php";

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

if((!$login) || (!$senha)){

    echo "<script>window.alert('Por favor, todos campos devem ser preenchidos!');</script>";
    include "index.php";

}
else{

    $senha = md5($senha);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM membros WHERE login='{$login}' AND senha='{$senha}' AND ativado='1'");
    $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($login_check > 0){

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

            foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){

                $$key = stripslashes( $val );

            }

            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
            $_SESSION['autor'] = $autor;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

            mysql_query("UPDATE membros SET data_ultimo_login = now() WHERE id ='{$id}'");

            header("Location:/admin/inicio/");

        }

    }
    else{

        echo "<script>window.alert('Acesso negado tente nova mente');</script>";

        include "index.php";

    }
}

?>
```

function.php

```
<?php

function session_checker(){

    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){

        header ("Location:/admin/");

        exit(); 
    }
}

function verifica_email($EMAIL){

    list($User, $Domain) = explode("@", $EMAIL);
    $result = @checkdnsrr($Domain, 'MX');

    return($result);

}

?>
```

Proteger as seções. verificando se o usuário esta logado coloco isso no inicio da pagina

```
<?php include("config.php");
session_start();
include "functions.php";
session_checker(); ?>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_REQUEST['logmeout'])){

    echo "Voc&ecirc; realmente deseja sair da &aacute;rea restrita?<br />";
    echo "<a href=\"logout.php?logmeout\">Sim</a> | <a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">N&atilde;o</a>";

}
else{
    session_destroy();


        include "index.php";


}
?>
```

Comment: Tentou colocar um campo ativo no banco de dados? Ao logar, verificar se for 1, esta logado, se não seta 1 pra deixar como logado.. se ele ja estiver com 1, ele não permite um novo login, e na hora de sair, coloque o ativo como zero, pra liberar acessos... só precisa ver a questão quando fechar o navegador, pra fazer isto automatico também.

Comment: Exatamente isso ai que estou precisando no caso a questão de deletar caso a pagina seja fechada por segurança ou que tenha no caso um tempo de duração. Dei uma editada na pergunta.

Comment: Tente fazer conforme te disse... pra ver, e ai vamos ver aqui se alguém sabe como faz na hora de fechar o navegador, se ele da um set ativo = 0, pra deslogar e liberar acesso a outros

Comment: Mais no caso só uma duvida se o usuário que logou fechar o navegador sem deslogar para aplicar a destruição do session bem como fazer update valor 0 o usuário não iria ficar impedido de entrar com da mesma forma que outro usuário que esteja tentando usar o mesmo login e senha ?

Comment: Foi o que eu te disse... temos que ver aqui com o pessoal se alguém se habilita a ajudar pra gente tentar resolver... se ele fechar sem sair, acho que teria que dar um set ativo 0, na hora de fechar o navegador... deve ter algum jquery que faça isso...

Comment: Acho que achei o que eu preciso olha só http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33867/realizar-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-fechar-navegador

Comment: Ok, acho que seria isso mesmo...

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta... se for útil, dê um aceite. Valeu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei oque eu queria agradeço ajuda de todos deixo abaixo o código  caso alguém  queira usar.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
// seta configurações  hora e tempo limite de inatividade//
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
$tempolimite = 900;
//fim das configurações de hora e limite de inatividade//

// aqui ta o seu script de autenticação no momento em que ele for validado você seta as configurações abaixo.//
// seta as configurações de tempo permitido para inatividade//
 $_SESSION['registro'] = time(); // armazena o momento em que autenticado //
 $_SESSION['limite'] = $tempolimite; // armazena o tempo limite sem atividade //
// fim das configurações de tempo inativo//
?>
```

Coloque o código abaixo nas paginas onde você quer verificar o tempo de atividade.

```
<?php
    $registro = $_SESSION['registro'];
    $limite = $_SESSION['limite'];
    if($registro)// verifica se a session  registro esta ativa
    {
     $segundos = time()- $registro;
    }
    // fim da verificação da session registro

    /* verifica o tempo de inatividade 
    se ele tiver ficado mais de 900 segundos sem atividade ele destrói a session
    se não ele renova o tempo e ai é contado mais 900 segundos*/
    if($segundos>$limite)
    {
     session_destroy();
     die( "Sua seção expirou.");

    }
    else{
     $_SESSION['registro'] = time();
    }
    // fim da verificação de inatividade
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Crie um campo chamado `ativo` em sua base de dados, ao efetuar o login, sete como 1, e ao fazer logout sete como 0. Feito login, verifique se for o `ativo=1`, você coloca a mensagem: este usuário já está logado, caso contrário, faz login... 
E ao fechar o navegador, use a resposta do nosso colega:
[Realizar ação ao fechar navegador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33867/realizar-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-fechar-navegador)
E sete `ativo=0`

Answer (score 1):

cara 2 opção coloca uma função na pagina de login que caso ja esteja logado envia pra pagina restrita sua.... ou coloca no banco de dados um novo campo status e manda verificar ele na hora de logar... caso ele tente e ja esta logado envia uma mensagem falando que ja esta logado em outro dispositico

Comment: Isso eu já entendi no caso mais como perguntei acima pro André vai dar o problema perguntado acima para ele ?

Answer (score 1):

Minha solução foi bem simples: Basicamente fiz no banco fiz o seguinte:

```
Alter Table usuarios add session_id varchar(255);
```

depois toda vez que o usuário logava eu fazia um update no banco via php:

```
UPDATE `usuarios` SET `session_id` = '" .session_id()."' WHERE `usuarios`.`id` = " . $resultado['id']
```

E então adicionei um php em todos as paginas como se fosse um "Header" que verificava se o session id do usuário era igual o session id que tava atualmente no banco de dados:

```
$result_auth = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id =" . $_SESSION['idUsuario'];
        $resultado_auth = mysqli_query($conn, $result_auth);
        $resultadoauth = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_auth);
        if($resultadoauth['session_id']==session_id()){



        }else{

            header("Location: ". $urlproduto ."sair?voltou=true");

        }
```

Bom, Isso resolveu pra mim, toda vez que alguém loga e a conta já está logada o session_id muda desconectando quem já está logado!

Espero que tenha ajudado, Abs!

Comment: Não seria interessante dizer que alguém já está logado ao tentar logar ?